# Can anybody recognize this time format?

Tags: json, date, time

I'm processing an undocumented JSON with a field that's supposed to be time. One entry for example is `638304962552130000`, and another is `638304890430100000`. Does that correspond to any standard format? The two numbers are supposed to be about one day apart. Both are in the recent past (few days), that's all I know.

It's definitely not Unix time. The distance between the two numbers indicates it might be microseconds (then it's approx. 20 hours) but then the epoch starts 20,000 years ago. If it's a number of nanoseconds on the other hand, the beginning of the epoch would be some time in mid 2003.

Comment: any more info about the file / application it came from?

Comment: also, are those the actual values that appear in the file or are they embedded in a string?  numeric values in JSON tend to be doubles so the last couple of digits of those numbers woudn't be preserved.  presumably this is for transfer between languages with a more developed type system than JavaScript?

Comment: @SamMason it appears as a string, and I have no idea what application generated it. I seem to have found the solution (posted as a self answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think now that the most reasonable solution is that this is a count of 10⁷ ticks per second since January 1 of the year 1 (AD). I was able to confirm that the timestamp `638306693622670000` matches 2023-09-18 21:29:22 UTC, and that [works out](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=63830669362.267+seconds+before+2023-09-18+21%3A29%3A22+UTC). Very strange indeed that somebody would use that for time!

Comment: [Windows "file time"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/file-times) uses 100ns unit (i.e. 1e7/s) but an epoch of 1601 AD not 1 AD.

Comment: Extending the Gregorian calendar before it was invented, let alone used seems, unnecessary.  Ah well, at least it's encoded as a string suggests they know what they're doing and hence common issues with numbers that big.